# Delete row instances if column instance appears in the majority

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a 2D list similar to this (but much larger):

```
data = 
[[ 1.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 2.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 3.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 4.      data.       data.      data. ] 
 [ 1.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 2.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 3.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 4.      data.       data.      data. ] 
 [ 1.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 2.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 3.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 4.      data.       data.      data. ] 
 [ 1.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 2.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 3.      data.       data.      data. ]
 [ 4.      data.       data.      data. ]]
```

And a reference list similar to this:

```
reff = [X, Y, X, Y, Y, Y, Y, X, Y]
```

Along with this, I have a list of indices similar to this:

```
idxs = [i for i, x in enumerate(reff) if x == "X"]
```

I used this to get a smaller 2D list:

```
smaller_data = [data[I] for i in idxs]
```

Within this `smaller_data`, I want to search the columns for consistent values (above a threshold) and then remove all of those instances from the original 2D list.

For example `if` it is determined that in the third index of every inner-list (Essentially the entire fourth column of `smaller_data`) has the same value `XYZ` appearing at least 65% of the time, then I want to delete all instances (rows) of in `data` where the third index (fourth column) has a value of `XYZ`.

This is the code I have:

```
thresh = 0.65
to_remove = []

transposed = [list(i) for i in zip(*smaller_data)]
col_idx = []
col_id = 0
for col in transposed:
    unique = set(col)
    for val in unique:
        freq = float(col.count(val))/float(len(col))
        if freq > threshold:
            to_remove.append(val)
            col_idx.append(col_id)
col_id += 1


for row in data:
    for idx in col_idx:
        if row[idx] == to_remove[idx]:
            data.remove(row)

return data
```

This doesn't seem to work. I get a `list index out of range` error for the line `if row[idx] == to_remove[idx]`. I am unsure as to how to go about this. What am I missing?

Comment: When you remove a row from your matrix, all indices below this row must shift. Instead of removing rows by index, I'd go with collecting a set of _values_ to remove (value-column pairs, if I understand your approach correctly), and create a new table by scanning the source table and checking rows.